# Проверка вводимых символов на русские буквы с пробелами

Tags: php, javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка ввода, в которую пользователь должен вписывать Имя
Так же допускается написать Иван Иванов

Сейчас строка ввода проверяется по такому регулярному выражению

```
name_pattern = '^[А-Яа-яЁё]*$';
```

и оно не пропускается пробелы
подскажите, как его дополнить чтобы допускался ввод нескольких слов с пробелами?

Comment: ['~^(?i:\pL+(?:\s?\pL+)*)$~u'](https://regex101.com/r/sHBNJD/5) это для php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Доброе утро

```
name_pattern = '#^[А-Яа-яЁё ]+$#u';
```

или более правильный

```
name_pattern = '#^[а-яё\s]+$#iu';
```

обязательно надо использовать "u", чтобы регулярное выражение понимало кириллицу
Есть куча онлайн ресурсов для проверки регулярных выражений, например [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/sHBNJD/1)

Comment: Вы путаете PHP и JavaScript: для PHP пишите тогда уж `$name_pattern`, а для JavaScript не нужен модификатор `u`.